# Physical device not showing up for Android Phonegap project created with Applaud plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, applaud

I'm building my first phonegap with Jquery Mobile app. I'm running Linux Mint 13 and I have installed MDS AppLaud for PhoneGap with Eclipse, following these instructions: http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start. Everything worked fine and I can create a Phonegap for Android Project. This runs fine with the AVD.

To run it on a physical device (a samsung galaxy 2), I followed these instructions (from http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt0):

1/ Attach the Android device to your development host, confirm USB and debugging are enabled on your device 
2/ Select your project at the top level in the Project Explorer 
3/ From the top menu bar select Run -> Run Configurations 
    The Run Configurations window should look similar to the image in AVD section above
4/ Verify your project is selected under Android Application, and in the Name field at the top
5/ Select the Target tab (between Android and Common tabs)
6/ Select Manual (as opposed to the Automatic selection in AVD instructions)
7/ Select Run to get to the next window, as shown below

But when I select "Run", the Android Device Chooser does not show any devices.

When I create an ordinary Android Project (File > New > Android Application Project) and run it, the device does show up and it runs fine on the phone.

Any ideas why a phonegap project created with the Applaud plugin will not run on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file, I changed

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

and this solved the problem.